# Expect script if command won't run

Tags: tcl, expect

Can anyone help me with the following. I think it could be due to whitespace but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

This is supposed to be a simple script that will move a file depending on it's location. I'm using expect as I want it to be handled on my NAS (via ssh), rather than taking the file off and putting it back on just to move it between shares.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Script to organise downloaded file

set FileDir [lindex $argv 0]
set FileName [lindex $argv 1]
set MiscDir "/media/Misc/Downloads"
set DownDir "/media/Downloads"

if { [string compare $FileDIR  $DownDir]  = 0 } {

} elseif { [string compare $FileDIR  $MiscDir]  = 0 } {
        spawn ssh *****@*******
        expect "assword:"
        send "********\r"
        expect "$ "
        send "mv ~/Misc/Downloads/$FileNAME '~/Misc/To Convert/$FileNAME'"
        expect "$ "
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof'
}
```

**Updated Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Script to organise downloaded file

set FileDir [lindex $argv 0]
set FileName [lindex $argv 1]
set MiscDir "/media/Misc/Downloads"
set DownDir "/media/Downloads"

if { [string compare $FileDir  $DownDir]  == 0 } {

} elseif { [string compare $FileDir  $MiscDir]  == 0 } {
        set OrigFile "\"/shares/Misc/Downloads/$FileName\""
        set MoveFile "\"/shares/Misc/To Convert/$FileName\""
        spawn ssh Admin@Appledore
        expect "assword:"
        send "xxxxxxxx\r"
        expect "$ "
        send "mv $OrigFile $MoveFile"
        expect "$ "
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof'
}
```

**Debug Output**

```
spawn ssh Admin@Appledore parent: waiting for sync byte parent: telling child to go ahead parent: now unsynchronized from child spawn: returns {5222}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "assword:"? no Admin@appledore's password:  expect: does "Admin@appledore's password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "assword:"? yes expect: set expect_out(0,string) "assword:" expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6" expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Admin@appledore's password:" send: sending "*******!\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "$ "? no


expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "$ "? no [Admin@Appledore ~]$  expect: does " \r\n[Admin@Appledore ~]$ " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "$ "? yes expect: set expect_out(0,string) "$ " expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6" expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\n[Admin@Appledore ~]$ " send: sending "mv "/shares/Misc/Downloads/NOOBS_lite_v1_4.zip" "/shares/Misc/To Convert/NOOBS_lite_v1_4.zip"" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "$ "? no <ownloads/NOOBS_lite_v1_4.zip" "/shares/Misc/To Convert/NOOBS_lite_v1_4.zip"                                      expect: does "mv "/shares/Misc/Downloads/NOOBS_lite_v1_4.zip" "/shares/Misc/To Convert/NOOBS_lite_v1_4.zip\r<ownloads/NOOBS_lite_v1_4.zip" "/shares/Misc/To Convert/NOOBS_lite_v1_4.zip"                          \u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "$ "? no
```

Comment: It would be clearer to write `if {$FileDir eq $DownDir}`

Comment: Also take care of your variable names: `$FileDir` is NOT the same variable as `$FileDIR`

Comment: Thanks glenn - I have done, I've updated the code quite a bit, but as stated below, it is appending exit to the end of the filename. Anyway around this?

Comment: Does it take longer than 10 seconds to perform that move? You might want to `set timeout -1` before that `send`

Comment: My test file is a 20Mb file which shouldn't take longer than 10 seconds (but seems to be) However some files I process are 2-3Gb in size. Am just trying it with the `set timeout -1`

Comment: It just seems to hang now

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your script to see expect's debugging output.

Comment: I've updated my original post with the output

Comment: Why do you think that mv command seems to hang? I don't see any clues from what you've shown.

Comment: No it's the mv command. I hadn't put `\r` after it (sorry - literally started with expect about 3 hours a go)

Comment: Ah! I usually notice that. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your = to ==

= is usually for assignment (and doesn't work in tcl. as commented below)

== is test for equalness

Comment: Thanks a lot - onto the next problem.

Comment: Actually, Tcl has no `=` operator **at all** (assignment is done with the `set` command). See the [`expr` documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm)

Comment: I've changed the majority of it, but I can't get it to wait to complete the mv command. For example I'm trying it with a zip file and it is appending 'exit' to the file extension when it moves it